# Version Control in Power Pages?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-collection

I am new to Power platform, coming from developer background, I am trying to understand do we have version control in Power Pages?
How to set up GitHub?

I tried searching, but didn't not find proper solution.
Expectation: I should be able to push, pull, commit and revert changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no native support for version control in Power Portals.
However, my current solution is as follows:

1. Download the Power Platform CLI ([Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/cli/introduction#install-power-platform-cli-for-windows) or [Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/cli/introduction#install-power-platform-cli-for-linuxmacos))
2. Authenticate to your environment with the [`pac auth create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/cli/reference/auth#pac-auth-create) command
3. Get your website ID using [`pac paportal list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/cli/reference/paportal)
4. Download your website using [`pac paportal download`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/cli/reference/paportal) (if that command doesn't work, it may be because your site is using the Enhanced data model. In that case, add `--modelVersion 2` at the end)
5. Add the downloaded directory to a freshly initialized Git repo on your favourite repo host
6. Set up a CI/CD pipeline to publish your code when triggered, see [this blog post](https://swimburger.net/blog/dynamics/how-to-deploy-power-apps-portals-using-azure-pipelines) for instructions